# Why is my inflator in this fragment a null object reference?

Tags: android, return, fragment, nullreferenceexception

After recently changing an activity to a fragment i have used the Layoutinflator to grab the user interface for the fragment however i have come across a runtime error that is shown in the LOGCAT below how can i fix this?

```
public class MainInstagramActivity extends Fragment {
private InstagramSession mInstagramSession;
private Instagram mInstagram;

private ProgressBar mLoadingPb;
private GridView mGridView;

private static final String CLIENT_ID = "83549f9eb76f4a5b90daf6e4e14da107";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "6df26b0c8f664323a07126bfe8511651";
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://www.yahoo.com";



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (mInstagramSession.isActive()) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_user_instagram, null);
        return view;
    }
    else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_main_instagram, null);

        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(container, savedInstanceState);

    mInstagram          = new Instagram(getActivity(), CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

    mInstagramSession   = mInstagram.getSession();

    if (mInstagramSession.isActive()) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_user_instagram, null);




        InstagramUser instagramUser = mInstagramSession.getUser();

        mLoadingPb = (ProgressBar)container.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);
        mGridView   = (GridView)container.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(instagramUser.fullName);
        ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_username)).setText(instagramUser.username);

        ((Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mInstagramSession.reset();

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainInstagramActivity.class));

                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });

        ImageView userIv = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.iv_user);

        DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(false)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity())
                .writeDebugLogs()
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions)
                .build();

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

        AnimateFirstDisplayListener animate  = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        imageLoader.displayImage(instagramUser.profilPicture, userIv, animate);

        new DownloadTask().execute();



    } else {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_main_instagram, null);

        ((Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mInstagram.authorize(mAuthListener);
            }
        });

}
}
```

LOGCAT

```
09-22 10:41:31.065      986-986/com.virtualinsomniac.annaakana E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.virtualinsomniac.annaakana, PID: 986
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean instagramlibrary.InstagramSession.isActive()' on a null object reference
        at com.virtualinsomniac.annaakana.Instagram.MainInstagramActivity.onCreateView(MainInstagramActivity.java:63)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1704)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1448)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:738)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
```

Comment: look at the method declaration, what are you saying you are going to return?

Comment: Maybe just call super.onCreateView(...) at the end?

Comment: you should probably read [the Android reference documents about fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) before continuing any further, your current implementation won't work as getView() will return null until onCreateView() has finished execution

Comment: @panini I have read that page and I did some further research and I believe my return statements should now work in regards to finishing onCreateView I was under the impression that the entirety of the code had to be within this instead of on create as its a fragment?

Comment: generally the way to do it is create and return the view in onCreateView(), and then do any set up of the view within the onViewCreated() method

Comment: @panini so ive added onViewCreated (edited original code) but i get an error on override for some reason and i still have the null problem

Comment: you get a compiler error around the @override annotation because you aren't using the correct method signature.

Comment: @panini this method signature is wrong? "public void onViewCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(container, savedInstanceState);" how so?

Comment: yes. [read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: @panini okay the compiler error is fixed however im still getting a null returned even with the onViewCreated that i have added

Comment: you're still calling getView() from onCreateView(), so of course you're still getting NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: @panini okay so i have moved the bulk of the code to onViewCreated and put my creating of views in onCreateView however i get the error above? i need a different view to be set in regard to whether a class is active or not

Answer (score 0):

This returns a view so instead of inflating the view in your fragment maybe you can return that view and inflate it in your activity.

Comment: question has been updated if you could take a look in your free time thank you

Comment: Dominic read my comments on the OP, they answer your question.